# Spring Boot and how to configure connection details to MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-boot

Being new to Spring Boot I am wondering on how I can configure connection details for MongoDB. 
I have tried the normal examples but none covers the connection details.

I want to specify the database that is going to be used and the url/port of the host that runs MongoDB.

Any hints or tips?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Just to quote [Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.nosql.mongodb.connecting):

> You can set `spring.data.mongodb.uri` property to change the url, or alternatively specify a `host/port`. For example, you might declare the following in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongoserver
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

All available options for `spring.data.mongodb` prefix are fields of `MongoProperties`:

```
private String host;

private int port = DBPort.PORT;

private String uri = "mongodb://localhost/test";

private String database;

private String gridFsDatabase;

private String username;

private char[] password;
```

Comment: Hey, would I do the same for a normal webapp using Spring boot? Where can I find the application.properties file?

Comment: You need to write it yourself, if you don't want to rely on default options: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Note that there is currently an issue if you want to set the password field as it is a char[]. Instead use the uri field. See the bottom of this bug report: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/536

Comment: Where are configuration properties like `spring.data.mongodb.host` documented? Do I have to just look at the `MongoProperties` class API documentation or source code? (Note that the particular quote that starts this answer no longer seems to appear in the Spring Boot documentation mentioned; neither does `spring.data.mongodb.uri` appear in the [Spring Data MongoDB - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/).)

Comment: Fixed the link in the answer to the actual doc

Answer (score 54):

It's also important to note that MongoDB has the concept of "**authentication database**", which can be different than the database you are connecting to. For example, if you use the [official Docker image for Mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) and specify the environment variables `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`, a user will be created on '**admin**' database, which is probably not the database you want to use. In this case, you should specify parameters accordingly on your `application.properties` file using:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=<username specified on MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME>
spring.data.mongodb.password=<password specified on MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD>
spring.data.mongodb.database=<the db you want to use>
```

Comment: it's not `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` but `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` in case of a `password`.

Comment: You saved me with this one man. Thank you

Answer (score 46):

`spring.data.mongodb.host` and `spring.data.mongodb.port` are not supported if you’re using the **Mongo 3.0 Java driver**. In such cases, `spring.data.mongodb.uri` should be used to provide all of the configuration, like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345
```

Comment: What if you don't have a user or password?

Comment: @Jesse in that case its fine, by default mongo does not requires any authentication so the connection would work in that case.

Comment: Is there any option to give autoreconnect in spring.data.mongodb.uri ?

Comment: wil it work for standalone spring data application ?

Comment: Secret in a properties file is fishy. Goes straight into the VCS unencrypted.

Comment: how can i connect if my password has "@" in it ?

Answer (score 24):

In a maven project create a file `src/main/resources/application.yml` with the following content:

```
spring.profiles: integration
# use local or embedded mongodb at localhost:27017
---
spring.profiles: production
spring.data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://<user>:<passwd>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>
```

Spring Boot will automatically use this file to configure your application. Then you can start your spring boot application either with the integration profile (and use your local MongoDB)

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=integration your-app.jar
```

or with the production profile (and use your production MongoDB)

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production your-app.jar
```

Comment: Is there any option to give autoreconnect in spring.data.mongodb.uri ?

Answer (score 19):

You can define more details by extending AbstractMongoConfiguration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("demo.mongo.model")
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profileActive;

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String proAppName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String mongoHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private String mongoPort;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String mongoDB;

    @Override
    public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext()
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.mongoMappingContext();
    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient(mongoHost + ":" + mongoPort);
    }
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mongoDB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the username and password specified? It gives unauthorized excaption, when we just define it in the applicaiton.properties and then extend AbstractMongoConfiguration.

Comment: It will be inside application.properties

Comment: Is it right using profile variable to do this? `if(profileActive=="dev"){ return new Fongo(getDatabaseName()).getMongo();} else { return new MongoClient(url, port); }`

Answer (score 5):

In case that somebody is trying to connect to a Atlas MongoDB Cluster in application.properties has to have a config like:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://databaseUsername:usernamePassword@cluster0.j4koa.mongodb.net/databaseUsername?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to set up MongoDB for integration tests using Testcontainers. Using properites file was not an option since Mongo port had to be specified during runtime. I wanted to preseve original MongoDB autoconfiguration provided by SpringBoot but override some of the properties. This can be achieved by defining a bean of type `MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer` which can be used to customize mongo settings :

```
@Bean
public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer clientSettingsBuilderCustomizer(final GenericContainer<?> mongoDBContainer) {
     String database = environment.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.database");
     ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(String.format("mongodb://localhost:%s/%s", mongoDBContainer.getFirstMappedPort(), database));
     return settings -> settings.applyConnectionString(connectionString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to read a MongoDB connection string from an environment variable, one way is to set the following environment variable:

```
SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/trying-mongo
```

This doesn't require any changes in the `application.properties` as the spring data mongo will read the value from the above environment variable by default.

Answer (score 0):

Here is How you can do in **Spring Boot 2.0** by creating custom MongoClient adding Providing more control for Connection  ,

Please follow  [github Link for Full Source Code](https://github.com/Sanjay007/Spring-boot-Custom-MongoConfiguration)

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "com.frugalis.repository" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.frugalis.*" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MongoJPAConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${com.frugalis.mongo.database}")
    private String database;
    @Value("${com.frugalis.mongo.server}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${com.frugalis.mongo.port}")
    private String port;
    @Value("${com.frugalis.mongo.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${com.frugalis.mongo.password}")
    private String password;


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.frugalis.entity.mongo";
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {

        List<MongoCredential> allCred = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
        System.out.println("???????????????????"+username+" "+database+" "+password+" "+host+" "+port);
        allCred.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray()));
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient((new ServerAddress(host, Integer.parseInt(port))), allCred);
        client.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);

        return client;
    }}
```

Comment: Here's how?  What - adding a class?  What is JPA?  Where are your imports in this file?  This is an incomplete answer at best.