# Dockerize spring boot mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, web-services, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize a spring boot web app with mongodb backend.
I run mongo and map it to host with following command:

```
docker run -p27017:27017 --name my-mongodb-container -d mongo:latest
```

I have built a jar with spring boot code and am able to run it successfully. It inserts and prints some data.
Now I dockerize this jar with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

I run the docker container as:

```
docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest --link my-mongodb-container doc40
```

The instance comes up, tries to connect to mongo an fails. But the app get loaded as I have another url that functions properly. However, it just returns hard coded data.

The error that i see in the console

```
2021-09-23 17:13:02.725  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {
hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-09-23 17:13:02.824  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread whi
le connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-cor
e-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
```

Any inputs are much appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work.

The only change I did was to connect the instance to preferred n/w on startup.

```
docker run -p27017:27017 --name my-mongodb-container --network=app-network -d mongo:latest

docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest --network=app-network -e SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://my-mongodb-container:27017/test doc40
```

I was trying to run the container and then add it to a n/w.

Answer (score 1):

The problem begins with your *connectionString* to mongoDb and the architecture of containers

You are trying to connect to localhost:27017 from the java container. In the java container, Mongo is not running. Instead is running in another container. You have to change your connection string to point to ***my-mongodb-container:27017***

I'll recommend using docker networks instead of --link since it is deprecated
https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

I'll give you a quick example

```
docker network create -d brigde app-network
docker run -p27017:27017 --name my-mongodb-container -d mongo:latest
docker network connect app-network my-mongodb-container
docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest doc40
docker network connect app-network mydoctest
```

(I have not tested it, let me know if there is any mistake)

Depends on the Mongo driver you are using to you have to set 2 different variables to change your connection string as stated in [Spring Boot and how to configure connection details to MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515295/spring-boot-and-how-to-configure-connection-details-to-mongodb)

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1

So you can create the container respectively using

```
docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest -e SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://my-mongodb-container:27017 doc40
or
docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest -e SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=my-mongodb-container doc40
```

Comment: Hi bipe15,
I ran the following commands:

`docker network create app-network
docker run -p27017:27017 --name my-mongodb-container -d mongo:latest
docker network connect app-network my-mongodb-container
docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest doc40`


`docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest -e SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017 doc40`

Now I am getting:

`Caused by:  'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgument
**Exception: Database name must not be empty!**`

Comment: Right, docker run -p 4444:8080 --name mydoctest -e SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://my-mongodb-container:27017/test doc40. Mind I added the /test in the connection and also point to my-mongodb-container, not to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Simply not connecting... after adding the host and DB, its throwing socket exception. I ran the jar on localhost and it connects without any issues to mongodb in docker. But I copy the jar to docker and I am able to access the URL and it is unable to connect to mongo. I use localhost to invoke the url. Both in case of running a jar on localhost or on docker... everything is same. The only difference is the dokcer container where I host my spring jar.

Answer (score 0):

What's the IP address of your Docker host machine?

Your app tries to connect to Mongo using *localhost*. Depending on what Docker installation you are using (taking the problem into account I assume Docker Toolbox), *localhost* won't work. You might try the IP address of Docker host instead of *localhost*. Most of the times, the IP is *192.168.99.100* but could be something else as well.

You can find the address by executing *docker-machine ip* using Docker command line.

Comment: Hi KDW,

following is the docker inspect o/p

`docker inspect <SPRING CONTAINER>

"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",


docker inspect <mongo container>
"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",`

Comment: Those are addresses used by Docker for the different containers and are different from the docker host address. Try the docker-machine command mentioned in the previous answer and see its output. Try to use this address instead of localhost in your connection string. Also take a look at @bipe15's comment since this is probably a more generic approach compared to my answer.

Comment: Actually, I am on windows. I am using docker desktop. I am unable to find the docker-machine  command.

Comment: Are you sure your Mongo container is running and accessible when the application is started? Can you access Mongo using localhost:27017 with some kind of GUI (e.g. MongoDB Compass)? I don't think Docker Desktop is using 192-addresses for the host anymore.

Comment: yes....So i run the spring boot jar through java -jar myapp.jar

when I access the app from browser it does insert and read the values from mongo. I am also running mongo and have access to command prompt of the container. I am able to connect through mongo console and view the collections and docs created..