# Cannot find the MongoClient class in the com.mongodb.client package provided by SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

---

For few hours I am trying to find the solution for this issue but could not resolve it for my own.
The problem is that my Spring Boot Application needs a MongoConfiguration class which should create a MongoClient object for further use to create a MongoTemplate object and it seems like I do not have a required dependency. I am curious if Spring does not provide it automaticly or I am doing something wrong, but every guide about how to create the mongoTemplate Bean says it is so easy - "just make a config class with the MongoClient object, blablabla, it is ready!" but I can not even use this class.

The Config class looks like this ( the showed imports are not recognized by the compiler ):

```
...
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;    
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "pizzeria";
}

@Override
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/pizzeria");
    MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .build();

    return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
}

@Override
public Collection getMappingBasePackages() {
    return Collections.singleton("pl.mvasio.pizzeria.data");
}
}
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.mvasio</groupId>
    <artifactId>pizzeria</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pizzeria</name>
    <description>Design and order your favorite pizza</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.4.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.4.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As you can see i have tried to add additional dependency - mongo-java-driver and it helped with this issue but unfortunately provides another one so i need to resolve this. I will be really grateful for any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a  recent project with one of the dependencies as `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>`, and it works fine without the explicit dependency of MongoDB Java Driver.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks a lot for your answer. Just tried this before reading your comment, but still appreciate. And yes, it works with this artifactId!

Answer (score 0):

You can conect to mongo directly trough the application.properties

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:pwd@ip1:port1,ip2:port2/database`

using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

also you can:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=<username specified on MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME>
spring.data.mongodb.password=<password specified on MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD>
spring.data.mongodb.database=<the db you want to use>
```

depending on your driver.

You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515295/spring-boot-and-how-to-configure-connection-details-to-mongodb)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but thanks for your time. The issue has now been resolved due to the comment below the question.