# Connecting to a Mongo container from Spring container

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem here that I really cannot understand. I already saw few topics here with the same problem and those topics was successfully solved. I basically did the same thing and cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

I have a Spring application container that tries to connect to a Mongo container through the following **Docker Composer**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
      
  db:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

In my **application.properties**:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db:27017/app
```

Finally, my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /home/java
RUN mkdir /home/java/bar
COPY ./build/libs/foo.jar /home/java/bar/foo.jar
CMD ["java","-jar", "/home/java/bar/foo.jar"]
```

When I run `docker compose up --build` I got:

```
2022-11-17 12:08:53.452  INFO 1 --- [null'}-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server db:27017

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db
```

Running the `docker compose ps` I can see the mongo container running well, and I am able to connect to it through Mongo Compass and with this same Spring Application but outside of container. The difference running outside of container is the host from `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db:27017/app` to `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/app`.

Also, I already tried to change the host for localhost inside of the spring container and didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify MongoDB host, port and database as different parameters as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515295/spring-boot-and-how-to-configure-connection-details-to-mongodb).

`spring.data.mongodb.host=db`

`spring.data.mongodb.port=27017`

`spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin`

As per the official docker-compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) the above docker-compose file should worked since both `db` and `app` are in the same network (You can check if they are in different networks just in case)

If the networking is not working, as a workaround, instead of using `localhost` inside the spring container, use the server's IP, i.e, `mongodb://<server_ip>:27017/app` (And make sure there is no firewall blocking it)

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    # this will be a name of a container
    # default bridge network
    # no need for mongo port forwarding
  yourAppName:
    image: imagename
    container_name: yourAppContainerName # this will be a name of a container
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      # this overrides url in application properties 
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb/{dbName}
      # no need for port if default port is used
      # the part after this mongodb:// is a container name of mongo
```